# TYPO3 lists all tables in DB compare because of COLLATE

Tags: typo3, mariadb, typo3-8.x

I'm using TYPO3 8.7.4 with PHP 7.0.22 and MariaDB 10.2.7.

The DB Compare inside the InstallTool shows me that TYPO3 wants to alter all tables because the current value differs from the expected by the collation of the table:

```
ALTER TABLE `be_groups` CHANGE `title` `title` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL 
Current value: title VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '''' NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: The same here. This is so annoying...

Comment: i found this bugtracker entry: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/81610

but its related to the migration wizard. At least i am for sure it is a problem regarding these double quotes..

Comment: And a cross-link from a Forge issue to keep track on it: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82023

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE be_groups` before the change.

Comment: Which change? This is a fresh installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB implemented a change to the Information Schema COLUMNS table which is not backwards compatible with the output expected from the 'original' MySQL:

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13132