# TYPO3 database analyzer utf8_general_ci server settings

Tags: database, macos, utf-8, typo3

I upgraded my development machine to High Sierra so I needed to reinstall Apache and PHP with Brew.

Now my local sites still work but on 8.7.8 installations the Database analyzer in the Install tool wants to alter a lot of fields in the same way, for example:

```
 ALTER TABLE `tt_content` CHANGE `header` `header` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL 
 Current value: header VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '''' NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

It looks like something has changed with utf8. On my testing server this is not happening, so I suspect it is a missing setting somewhere.

In Apache vhost.conf I have AddDefaultCharset utf-8

In php.ini default_charset = "UTF-8"

In mysql command

```
show variables like 'char%'; show variables like 'collation%';
```

shows all as utf-8 and collation_connection, collation_database and collation_server as utf8_general_ci

What could cause the result of the database analyser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [TYPO3 lists all tables in DB compare because of COLLATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737730/typo3-lists-all-tables-in-db-compare-because-of-collate)

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82023

In the process MariaDb was upgraded by Brew to 10.2.x.

I ended up removing MariaDB in Brew and installing MySQL, that fixed the problem.

I guess downgrading MariaDB to 10.1 also works.